# .NET 8.0 Global search or multi-page search

Tags: .net, xaml, maui, syncfusion, app.xaml

I'm thinking about adding a global search to my practice program, but I can only find solutions for local searches (same page search). I'm using both the Syncfusion Maui and the .NET Maui documents.

I'm following the following code:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/searchbar?view=net-maui-8.0 and

https://help.syncfusion.com/maui/datagrid/filtering

I should get a multi-page search from DataGrid, Dataform.

Comment: you're not going to find an out-of-the-box solution for this.  It will depend heavily on what your data is like and exactly what you want to search.  As written your question is really broad and unlikely to be answered